# Unit Testing using SystemWrapper and Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, systemwrapper

I have the method which makes backup of some file:

```
 public void MakeBackup(IFileWrap file, string path)
    {
        if (path  == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Console.WriteLine();

        string backups = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Backups\";

        if (!Directory.Exists(backups))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(backups);

        if (file.Exists(path))
        {
            file.Copy(path,backups + Path.GetFileName(path),overwrite: true);
            Console.WriteLine("Backup of the " + Path.GetFileName(path) + " lies in the " + backups);
        }


}
```

And Iam trying to test it by using SystemWrapper and Rhino Mocks:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void MakeBackupTest()
    {
        IFileWrap fileRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFileWrap>();

        fileRepository.Expect(x => x.Exists(@"G:\1.txt"));
        fileRepository.Expect(x => x.Copy(@"G:\1.txt", Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Backups\1.txt", overwrite: true));

        new Windows().MakeBackup(fileRepository,@"G:\1.txt");


        fileRepository.VerifyAllExpectations();

    }
```

The test above fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does it "fail"? Is it throwing an exception, or are the expectations failing? Please post the message or exception.

Comment: The debugger is the best tool for a programmer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting a return value for `fileRepository.Exists` - the default will be `false`. It should be something like:

```
fileRepository.Expect(x => x.Exists(@"G:\1.txt")).Return(true);
```